# Confusion between Steady flow and Space-Time invariant density field

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, fluid, compressible-flow

Let's take the example of a steady flow with velocity field as $u=βr(\tilde{r})$. Now, we can find a density field $ρ(r,t)$ that satisfies the mass conservation equation of $∂ρ/∂t+∇(ρu)=0$.

First, considering density to be only a function of time and with initial condition $ρ(0)=ρo$, we get $ρ(t)=ρ_oe^{−3βt}$. Second, considering density to be only a function of space, upon solving the differential equation, we get $ρ(r)=ρ_o/r^3$.

The interesting thing is, a density field of the form $ρ(t)+ρ(r)$ also satisfies the mass conservation equation and reflects the fact that for the given steady flow we can have a spatio-temporally varying density field! Isn't this counter-intuitive because as per my knowledge, we define steady flows as those where the velocity, density and pressure at a given point in space don't change with time?

I'm actually confused between the renowned definition of steady flows and the mathematical construct I've displayed above.

PS: The Wikipedia link that defined steady flows is-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_dynamics

Comment: This seems to belong solidly in Physics, not Engineering

Comment: Also, I don't see how you can have a density(t) that is not a constant to describe a "steady flow. "

Comment: @RC_23 sorry if I've mistakenly asked it here but I encountered this doubt as I'm currently pursuing my Mech major. As for your comment on how can density not be a constant, solving for density by using the mass conservation differential equation does yield the exponential relation I've stated above.

Comment: I believe steady flow by definition means all time derivatives are zero, so the first term in your continuity eqn vanishes.

Comment: Doesn't steady flow mathematically only imply local acceleration to be zero? That is, partial derivative of velocity vector to be zero?

Comment: No.  If that were true, no flow could happen in most cases. think of a closed piping system circulating water in a loop.  Anywhere there is a diameter increase or decrease, there will be a local deceleration or acceleration.  But it is considered steady flow because if you take a snapshot of it a t=1 sec, 5 sec, 1 hour, it is exactly the same. As opposed to 
the flow field in a bomb exploding, where there is a ton of outward motion which then dissipates.  Mathematically for steady flow, simply set all time derivatives to zero.

Comment: @RC_23 by 'local acceleration' to be zero, I meant ∂u/∂t to be zero.
I'll frame my confusion in a different way-
Imagine we've been given a velocity field (as above) that only depends on space. Now, our aim is to find a density field that conserves mass such that at t=0, density everywhere was _o. With this initial condition, we get the above stated exponentially decaying density field that's only a function of time.

Comment: In deriving it, I've not brought any terminologies like 'steady, or incompressible flows' as they're what we humans define. I've just used pure math. Moreover, for a different initial and boundary condition altogether, we can also get a density field that's (r)+(t), that conserves mass as well.
So, how do we ascertain which field is the correct one for a given boundary and initial condition?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780123821003/fluid-mechanics
Fluid Mechanics by Kundu also has a similar question (4.7, chapter-Conservation laws)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to do what you said, i.e. "Now, our aim is to find a density field that conserves mass such that at t=0, density everywhere was _o".... and that's fine, but per my understanding that would not be steady flow, it would be transient.  You would be altering the constraints of the problem.  "Steady flow" is not a human construct, it is a physical boundary condition that you can apply, or not.

Comment: That should answer your original question on terminology.  You were saying it's counter-intuitive to get a time varying field in steady flow. That's because it's a contradiction.  It'd be like saying a "constant velocity acceleration".

Comment: @RC_23, so does that mean we rule out the possibility of a time varying density field by first analyzing the velocity field? In the problem in question, the velocity field is just a function of space, so do we explicitly accept only those density field solutions given by our mass conservation equation that are time invariant? Even with this logic in mind, I'm still confused about one thing-why are we going out of our way to introduce the definition of a steady flow and its associated boundary conditions?

Comment: Let's assume we don't know anything about 'steady flows.' Now, with just the mass conservation equation up our sleeve, we aim to find the density field for the given velocity field. How do we ascertain which density field solutions exist, and which do not? Because mathematically, we've no idea that ∂u/∂t=0 implies ∂/∂t=0. 
Also, thanks for engaging in this discussion with me, it has really helped me think more :)